# How to filters arrays in Mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have one post with this property:

```
Ingredients: ['onions', 'carrots']
```

I'm finding this post with `$in` adding one of these ingredients.

But I need to find by 'onions' or/and 'carrots'. If I look for 'onion' and/or 'carrot' it doesn't work.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would return post with "carrots" and "onions" as ingredients:

Meteor way:

```
db.getCollection('food').find({ingredients:{$and: [
{ingredients: {
          $regex: `.*onion.*`,
          $options : 'i'
      }},
{ingredients: {
          $regex: `.*carrot.*`,
          $options : 'i'
      }}
]}})
```

MongoDB:

```
{$and:[{ingredients:/^onion/}, {ingredients:/^carrot/}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check both values exist in the array, use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator:

```
{ Ingredients: { $all: ['onions', 'carrots'] }}
```

If you want to check any value use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
{ Ingredients: { $in: ['onions', 'carrots'] }}
```

Comment: that's what I thought originally but with $all looking for 'onions' I get that post (which is correct) not with 'onion' I don't get anything

Comment: Found the way and it's working well on the terminal. Looking now the translation for Meteor:
db.getCollection('food').find({ingredients:{$all: [/^onions/, /^carrots/]}})

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create text index on Ingredients field. See [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) in MongoDB documentation. You can create index as (assuming your collection name is `collection`) for sake of brevity.

```
db.collection.createIndex({Ingredients:'text'})
```

Once your have your index created, search collection as

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:'onion'}})
```

You should get result back with minor variation like

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("599ad516619ebc3390b1c262"), 
    "Ingredients" : [ "onions", "carrots"] 
}
```

Comment: So I need to create an Index every time I need to get some data?

Comment: No. Only once on collection.

Comment: Ok, on every collection that I've got I need to create an index for each specific property on which I'm using an array?

Comment: "MongoDB provides text indexes to support text search queries on string content". Why is this necessary if you can find by $regex: `.*${searchString}.*`?
Maybe with this way is slithy faster, isn't?
The problem is that I've got many fields like this one and I don't want to make (another) mess cause I don't want to dig too deep on Mongo. If there is another way it's ok.
I'll give it a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for multiple "%like%" results here. Therefore put your search patterns into a regex array - you can then use this for your $all / $in queries.

i.e:-

```
var checkList = ["onion","carrot"];
var regexArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < checkList.length; i++) {
    regexArray[i] = new RegExp(checkList[i],"i");
}
db.collection.find({Ingredients:{$in:regexArray}})
```

If running in php, this translates to:-

```
$checkList = ["onion","carrot"];
$regexArray = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($checkList); $i++){
    $regexArray[$i] = new MongoRegex('/'.$checkList[$i].'/i');
}

$query = array('ingredients'=>array('$in'=>$regexArray));
```

Comment: with that if I look for "onions" I can't find anything

Comment: Apologies - I hadn't updated the field to "Ingredients" in the find command from the collection I was testing against. Should be ok now...

Comment: No, it's ok, I had the correct code (changed "$in : this.ingredients" for "$all : regexArray") but can't get any data as I said